# Converting Single Linklist to circular and verifying

Tags: python, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am new to datastructures. While learning circular linkedlist I am unable to progress further as I am stuck , I am trying to convert singly linkedlist to circular and then verifying the same. My program is not giving output and anyone please help me regarding it.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class Cll:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def push(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def makeCircular(self):
        temp = self.head
        while(temp.next != None):
            temp= temp.next
        temp.next = self.head

    def isCircular(self):
        temp = self.head
        while (temp.next != None):
            temp = temp.next
        if temp.next == self.head:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        #print(temp.data)
        while(temp!= None):
            print(temp.data, end = " ")
            temp = temp.next
        print("\n")

cll = Cll()
# l
for i in range(5):
    cll.push(i)
cll.printList()
cll.makeCircular()
print(cll.isCircular())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `isCircular()` method is broken because if it is circular, then `temp.next != None` will always be `True` and an infinite loop will occur.

Perhaps try something like this instead:

```
def isCircular(self):
    temp = self.head
    while temp.next is not None and temp.next is not self.head:
        temp = temp.next
    return temp.next is self.head
```